# Android GoogleAuthUtil returning only Unknown exception

Tags: android, xamarin, oauth-2.0, xamarin.android, google-oauth

I tried to setup my Android app to authenticate with my own server using OAuth 2.0. What I did:

- Creating a Web app in Google Developers Console (Project X).
- Creating a Android app in Google Developers Console (Project X) with the debug keystore (used by me app) and the package name of my app.
- Using the Web apps client id to get the token with GoogleAuthUtil.getToken() where the scope is "audience:server:client_id:" + the Web apps client id.

All I get is this "unknown" exception and while searching Stackoverflow and Google did't help me I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Are there additional steps that I need to take besides the ones I stated above? Even the smallest hint is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

```
com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown
at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallStaticObjectMethod (IntPtr jclass, IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue[] parms) [0x00064] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.21-series/9e05e39f/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:1161 
at Android.Gms.Auth.GoogleAuthUtil.GetToken (Android.Content.Context context, System.String accountName, System.String scope) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at MyProject.<chooserResult>b__3 () [0x00002] in MyProject\File.cs:171 
--- End of managed exception stack trace ---
com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown
at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

EDIT2:

I used GoogleAuthUtil.GetToken(Context, accName, googleAuthScope) where

- Context is the activity context
- accName is the accounts mail address
- googleAuthScope is the scope stated above: "audience:server:client_id:"

Comment: Can you paste the complete logtrace

Comment: @Ranjith I edited it on above post.

Comment: Also the code is also required to debug,..misssed mentioning that before

Comment: @Ranjith I used the code example from here: http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html

Comment: @LeviBotelho Sadly no :(

Comment: This is ridiculous. I'm going to try to find a workaround because nobody seems to have the solution. Will try to remember to come back and post the answer if I come across one :).

Comment: My problem was that I was using my client app's ID and not my web app's.  My working scope string looks like this `oauth2:server:client_id:<Web app client ID>:api_scope:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login`. Given that the error in my case was in the end an invalid scope string maybe that'll help you?

Comment: @LeviBotelho But why using "plus.login"? In my case I need a token to authenticate my own server and not GooglePlus...

Comment: You are authenticating the user with Google+. Google is  verifying their identity for you. You need their permission for Google to tell you that they are who they say they are.

Comment: @LeviBotelho I get what you mean, but the whole point in the above scope is that the user doesn't need to give permission. It's even on Google's site: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/CrossClientAuth

Comment: They do need to give their permission, but only once for a given set of scopes. Afterwards if I understand correctly you still need to request the scope, but the user won't be prompted because they will have already given their consent.

Comment: @LeviBotelho From the link above:

"One benefit of cross-client identity is that you can leverage it and ID tokens to enable Android apps to talk to their home server without requiring the user to log in."

So the whole point is still that they don't need to login, not even once.

Comment: Yes. Once you have the refresh token you can generate access tokens at will without user consent. But you need user consent *at some point* to get the access token. How do you expect to a) know who the user is, and b) get the user's consent (which you need) without the user ever logging in ever???

Comment: @LeviBotelho I don't need to know who the user is because of what I understand from the article above is that because I don't want any private information from my user I don't need their consent. Please have a look at this example: http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html It describes everything I tried to explain to you. :)

Comment: Okay I got it :). Sorry, I'm not doing the same workflow as you. I'm logging in users with their Google+ account, which is also mentioned on the page that you sent earlier.


Just to be sure, you are passing the client ID of the **web application** in the scope string (not the Android app) right? And in the Google Developer Console you have created a project for both your Android App **and** the web app, right?

Comment: Good, I was already thinking that maybe I just understood all of it wrong. :D Yeah, I created in **one** project an Android App and a Web App. I tried both IDs already.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use the keystore that Xamarin uses to generate the SHA1 signature for the client ID, as it isn't in the standard location:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\\bin\keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android -keystore "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore"
```

You can find the above command with the correct path in the deploy build logs. I had a similar issue logging in that was resolved after I updated the client ID with the signature from the xamarin keystore.

Comment: please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),it will be useful to help you to raise your content quality